# Synaptic Package Manager - Select Update in Bulk

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I am running *Mint 13*, both 32- and 64-bit versions. In general I prefer to use the *Synaptic Package Manager* as it handles the dependancies. One view shows you all the upgradeable packages. Is there a way to bulk select them all and then deselect the few you do wish to upgrade? Selecting them all one-by-one is a major pain.

Comment: Have you tried to click on top list, hold shift, click on the last and after that right click?

Comment: Does select all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left panel, select the “Status” filter, and choose the “Installed (upgradable)” list. You can select all packages in a view by clicking the first package, scrolling to the last package and shift-clicking it. Or with the keyboard, press <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. Then right-click or bring up the “Package” menu and select “Unmark” or “Mark for Upgrade”. You can also keep the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down to move around without changing the selection and click or press space to select the package under the cursor.

Comment: This works and I can then deselect the few I do not wish to upgrade such as vsFTPd which I had to backport (was refusing to run with writeable root inside chroot).

Comment: @MichaelJohn If you want to systematically omit a package from being upgraded, put it on hold (“Lock version” in Synaptic).

Comment: Useful - previously unaware of option...